# How to do onBackPress dialog in fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-event, onbackpressed

I was working on create a dialog that pop up to confirm whether the user exit the page.

In the past I used the activity so it has no problem. I just need to put the dialog inside the override `onBackPress` function, and call `finish()` if the user choose to leave.

However , currently I would like to switch the class to fragment inside a tabhost. So not only I need to handle the onbackpress but also the case when user click on the Tab bar to switch to other tab.

I tried:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(ctx);
    builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.quit_form));
    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.yes),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    File directory = new File(Constant.upload_imageFolder);
                    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
                        files[i].delete();
                    }
                    UploadForm.super.onDetach();
                }
            });
    builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.no),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

but it crash. How to fix the problem ? And is the onDetach correct function to override? Thanks a lot.

**Update:
The exception when ondetach:**

```
android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment UploadForm{42db9eb0 #3 id=0x7f050075} did not call through to super.onDetach()
```

Comment: What's the error? And if you replace `onDetach` with `onBackPressed` does it work? EDIT Look what I've found [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25574198/4385913) does it help?

Comment: the onBackPressed can not handle the case for press on menu tab and change tab

Comment: And what about if you try this using `setKeyListenerOnView` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27055873/4385913)?

Comment: that means I need to handle the case separately (1. backpress 2.on Menu tab click )? Also I updated the question , Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Override onBackPressed() in the Activity. and make all the FragmentTransaction are addToBackStack before commit.

```
 @Override public void onBackPressed() {
     int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

     if (count == 0) {
         super.onBackPressed();
         //additional code
     } else {
         getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
     }
 }
```

While the above approach would work for all fragments added to back stack . You can also customize it to follow a pattern.

1. Create an interface such as BackNavigable (implemented by those fragments who would like to consume back press) , with a method `boolean consumeBackPress();`
2. For those fragments who would like to consume back press event return true from the implementation.
3. Now inside activity onBackPressed() peek the current fragment and check if that fragment is instance of BackNavigable and has return true in  its `consumeBackPress()` implementation , If yes then pop that fragment otherwise call `super.onBackPressed()` of activity.

That's all.

Comment: thanks a lot , how about tab change when I press on the menu tab bar?

Comment: For tabs simply you will have to implement the same logic using child Fragment Manager  instead of FragmentManager.

Comment: for support library it must getSupportFragmentManager()